# ERROR: Cannot convert from DataAccess.Column to int?

Tags: c#, nullable, implicit-conversion

**Problem**: (Error) Cannot convert from 'DataAccess.Column' to 'int'?

**Background**: Using object from another solution

**I tried**: I tried casting it, but it did not get rid of the error. All of the SO articles I can find mentioned going from something like 'int to string' or 'int to int?' but not from database table object to int? (and vice versa).

**File with error**:

```
public si GetStuff(int iID) 
{
    using (var ctx = CreateContext())
    {
        var dao = ctx.DBTable.Where(x => x.ID == iID).ToList().Single();
        return new si.myObject(
            argsomeOtherID: dao.someOtherID;
            argColumnID: dao.Column;)
    }
}
```

**Other file (in other solution)**:

```
public class myObject {
                    public int someOtherID { get; private set;}
                    public int? ColumnID { get; private set;}

                    public myObject(int someOtherID, int? argColumnID);
                                                {
                                                    someOtherID = argsomeOtherID;
                                                    ColumnID = argColumnID;
                                                }
                      }
```

(namespace **DataAccess) Table.cs**:

```
public partial class DBTable
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }        
        public int someOtherID { get; set; }

        public virtual Column Column { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `dao.Column`?

Comment: You don't need `ToList` before `Single` that just creates an unnecessary list.

Comment: @SelimYıldız I added the c# code for the table. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Seems your last meaningful line `argColumnID: dao.Column;)` is using an actual Column instead of an int.  Does the Column property have an ID property of its own?  Perhaps it should be something like `argColumnID: dao.Column.ID`?  Or however you are supposed to get a the ID of a `Column` class.

Comment: Thanks @SeanSkelly. That was the case here. The even bigger problem ended up being with entityframework though and I had to remove and readd some things in the model, as it had not brought in the foreign key properly. I am good to go now. Thanks for your help. It seems so obvious now, but since I kept thinking "this should function like the other variables" I completely nixed out the possibility of what you mentioned here. Blindspot.